# Python: rect argument is invalid

Tags: python, pygame, arguments, rect, invalid-argument

Hi I'm trying to learn python and but i'm stuck with this problem, when i run my program it says rect argument is invalid, this is my code:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500,500))

pygame.display.set_caption("First game")

x = 50
y = 50
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0),(x, y, width, height, vel))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "...", line 25, in <module>
>    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0),(x, y, width, height, vel))
> TypeError: Rect argument is invalid
> ```

Comment: Your title doesn't seem to apply to your question at all.

Answer (score 3):

The 3rd argument of [`pygame.draw.rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/draw.html#pygame.draw.rect) has to be a tuple with 4 elements:

<s>`pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0),(x, y, width, height, vel))`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0),(x, y, width, height))
```

Alternatively it can be a [`pygame.Rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) object, too:

```py
rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, width, height)
pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), rect)
```